R- Plotly heatmap with aggregation
I try to plot a heatmap with plotly using the mean by groups, estimated through aggregation within the plotly fun. However, the result is not correct. Please help!
df=mtcars %>% mutate(gear=as.factor(gear),cyl=as.factor(cyl)) %>% select(cyl,gear,mpg)


plot_ly(df)  %>% group_by (cyl,gear) %>% 
  add_trace(
    x = ~ cyl,
    z = ~ mpg,
  
    type = 'heatmap',
    
    y=~gear,
 
    
    transforms = list(list(
      type = 'aggregate',
      groups =~ c(cyl,gear),
      aggregations = list(list(
        target = 'z',
        func = 'avg',
        enabled = T
      ))
        ))
)


I'm not sure what your goal is here, but I assumed that what you're looking for is generated in a much simpler way. plot_ly(df, x = ~cyl, y = ~gear, z = ~mpg, type = "heatmap") (Plotly's going to use mean by default by the x & y by default...no need for all that extra.)

thank you for the reply @Kat. However, I can see that the z value estimated in the table is not the mean in all cases (eg for gear=5 and cyl=4- at the upper left corner). any clues?

Wow, sorry I missed that...and I thought I double-checked. (Sigh.) Either way, here's a better-- working correctly answer: plot_ly(df, x = ~ cyl, y = ~gear, z = ~ mpg, histfunc = "avg", type = "histogram2d")
